# What exactly is OBD Calculated Load?

Tags: maf

OBD Calculated Load is defined as:

LOAD_PCT = [current airflow] / [(peak airflow at WOT@STP as a function of rpm) * (BARO/29.92) * SQRT(298/(AAT+273))]

But when I am in neutral and I open the throttle, calculated load does not change at all according to my OBD scan. It only changes when I am actually moving. I don't see how, according to the definition, that should matter.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a source for that formula?

Is it possible that you are reading [Calculated engine load value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_01), which would indeed be zero when you are in neutral?

[image: Calculated Engine Load Value]

- Range: 0 to 100
- Units: %
- Formula: A*100/255

I did find [this page](http://www.totalcardiagnostics.com/support/Knowledgebase/Article/View/43/6/reading-performance-information-data-pid) which defines it as:

> **Calculated Load Value** -- Indicates a percentage of peak available torque. Reaches 100% at wide open throttle at any altitude or RPM for both naturally aspirated and boosted engines.

In which case, I would still expect it to return non-zero values when in neutral, as it's not transmission load.

It looks like you're getting the formula from https://github.com/Knio/carhack/blob/master/old/can/pids.py, and if that formula is indeed correct and implemented correctly by the car's computer and manufacturer, then it "Reaches 100% at WOT at any altitude, temperature or rpm for both naturally aspirated and boosted engines", and should indeed be independent of vehicle speed or gear engagement (or lack thereof).

Comment: That definition is from the SAE standard J/1979, which defines the OBD PIDs. Thanks for your response.